# If a character shapeshifts into a larger creature, how do I determine their mass?

Tags: powers, creature-size, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I've got a character with the ability to shape shift into any animal. I've got everything else squared away, but I'm wondering about mass. If the character turns into a creature larger than what the character normally is do I add their original mass (rank 2 for humans) to the larger form, or do I strictly go by the mass granted by the Growth power modifer necessary for the form. So I'm asking is it

A: Mass Rank 2+(Growth Modifier)= 2+X

or

B: Growth Modifier=X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Increase your mass rank by your Growth rank.

According to the *Heroes Handbook*, p110, the Growth power effect adds your Growth rank to your original mass rank:

> Each rank of Growth adds 1 rank to your Strength and
>   Stamina (constructs add 1 rank to Strength and Tough-
>   ness if they lack Stamina) and adds 1 rank to your mass.

If your original mass is rank 2, and Growth rank is X, then using your Growth power means your new mass is rank 2+X.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Mike Q's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134923/if-a-character-shapeshifts-into-a-larger-creature-how-do-i-determine-their-mass/134926#134926), a common way of building characters who are more more massive, even if not really that much larger, is using Feature to add Mass on a 1 for 1 basis. For example, Jabroniville built both [Pink Pearl](http://www.echoesofthemultiverse.com/viewtopic.php?p=10773#p10773) and his [hippopotamus](https://roninarmy.com/threads/149-Jab-s-Builds!?p=93459&viewfull=1#post93459) build with two additional ranks of Mass.